# How can I get the number of free request threads from Java in a glassfish 3.1.2 server?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I'm looking for a java api way to do this, not an asadmin / CLI command. 
Although I've looked around here: http://glassfish.java.net/nonav/docs/v3/api/ 
I haven't seen it yet.

This configuration com.sun.grizzly.http.StatsThreadPool is how the min and max number of threads are configured (you can see this in the admin/console/web page). However, I want a real-time "read" of the current number of free threads (I'd settle for being able to calculate max - currently used)

My goal is to create a filter that implements [this sort of "I'm too busy" algorithm](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/01/building-a-node-js-server-that-wont-melt-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-5/), based on request thread usage.

Naturally, there are other measures you could use, but this measure is appropriate for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Monitoring GlassFish using AMX.

> AMX is an API that exposes all of the Enterprise Server configuration,
>   monitoring and JSR 77 MBeans as easy-to-use client-side dynamic
>   proxies implementing the AMX interfaces.`

You can query the Monitoring MBeans using this API. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/821-0181/beapd/index.html